# Ajax loadmore function not doing what I need

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a simple loadmore function, which sets the limit of a query and adds to the offset so only new items are loaded again. This works fine when I have 4 items to start with, but not when I want 8 to be displayed from the start.

My code:

```
var limit = 8;
var offset = 0;

$('#loadmoreprojects').click(function() {
    limit = 4;
    offset += 4;

    ajax();

});
```

Query:

```
$project                = "
SELECT ct.*, fe.*, cn.*
FROM 123_content ct
INNER JOIN 123_fieldsandfilters_elements fe on fe.item_id = ct.id
INNER JOIN 123_fieldsandfilters_connections cn on cn.element_id = fe.id
WHERE ct.catid IN ('10')
ORDER BY ct.ordering LIMIT ".$_POST['limit']." OFFSET ".$_POST['offset']."";
```

This shows 8 items from the start, but when loading more it shows the 2nd row again (the last 4 of the first 8 items). That makes sense because the limit is set to 4 again when clicking the button (because after the first 8, I only want 4 new items to be loaded) if I change it into 8, then 8 items are loaded on every click, which is not what I want.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var limit = 4;
var offset = 0;
var i =0;
$('#loadmorenews').click(function() {
    limit = 2;
    if(i == 0) {
        offset += 4;
    } else {
        offset += 2;
    }
    i++;

    ajax();

});
```